# How to put unprocessed (escaped) words inside String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, date, escaping, string-formatting

I am formatting a date:

```
str = String.Format("{0:MMM d m:mm"+yearStr+"}", dt);
```

I want to put the word "at" after the "d", but I don't want the string to format it. I just want the word "at".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can surround literal strings with quotes, which for longer strings is probably easier and a bit more readable than escaping every character with a backslash:

```
str = String.Format("{0:MMM d 'at' m:mm"+yearStr+"}", dt);
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in MSDN Library (search for "Literal string delimiter").

(And did you mean `h:mm` instead of `m:mm`?)

Comment: This solution worked best for me, the other answers, didn't let me using multiple blocks of {}..

Comment: (Or maybe even `H:mm` with capital `H`?)

Answer (score 14):

```
string.Format(@"{0:MMM d \a\t m:mm" + yearStr + "}", dt);
```

Note the double escaping - I used a varbatim string so I was able to write `\` inside the string as a normal character. The formatting routine for `DateTime` then interprets this (again) as an escape sequence.

Here is a simpler variant:

```
string.Format("{0:MMM d} at {0:m:mm" + yearStr + "}", dt);
```

The first variant might be considered disgusting by some. The latter one is very clear to read, though.

Comment: +1 I was trying to answer with  `string str = String.Format("{0:MMM} at {1:d m:mm"+yearStr+"}", dt, dt);`, but I think yours is better.

Comment: @MuhammadKashifNadeem it might work, but I don't care. I want to be sure it's correct and I want it to be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

**Using string interpolation (C# 6.0+):** ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated))

```
var yearStr = "2018";
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var str = $"{dt:MMM d \'at\' H:mm} {yearStr}";
```

*Backslash is optional*

```
var str = $"{dt:MMM d 'at' H:mm} {yearStr}";
```

see in action: [DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q6pbhY)

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, but works.

```
var what=new object[] { "{{{{0:MMM d}}}} {0} {{{{0:m:mm:{{0}}}}}}", "at", yearStr, dt };
var that=what.Aggregate((a, b) => String.Format((String)a, b));
```

You can merge two lines in one. The `at` which you want to put between two formats is also parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

if use for date naming directory path, backslash example as below:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
var str = d.ToString("yyyy\\\\MM\\\\dd");  // str = "2021\11\26"
```