# Date & time not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating my first win form application, written in C#. I have added a little bit of code to display the current date and time on the first tab page as below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // connect to database
        c = new Connection();
        connect.ConnectionString = c.getConnection();

        //deals with date and time
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 1000;//ticks every 1 second
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        tmr.Start();

    }
    private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labeltime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(" Todays Date: dd/MM/yyyy\n\n Current     Time: HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

The output in not correct however. The date and time are correct and ticking away nicely but where I want it to display "Todays Date:" it is messy like " To15a1342 (42 being the seconds from the time, ticking away) and the "Current Time" reads CuRRenP Ti50e:

Does it matter that I am in the UK? Would this require me to use different code or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is being interpreted as formatting strings, as explained in [`DateTime.ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The *`format`* parameter should contain either [...] a custom format pattern ([see Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx))

Only unrecognized characters are printed as-is, but as you noticed for example the `s` gets replaced by the value of `Seconds`.

To let `ToString()` ignore your text, you need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724183/how-to-put-unprocessed-escaped-words-inside-c-sharp-string-format) the literals, preferably with single quotes (`'`) (the alternative is a backslash in front of each literal):

```
 string dateTimeString = DateTime.Now
     .ToString("' Todays Date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'\n\n Current     Time: 'HH:mm:ss");
```

Or build up the string from separate parts:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
string dateTimeString = "' Todays Date: ";
dateTimeString += now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
dateTimeString += "\n\n Current     Time: ";
dateTimeString += now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Above string concatenation example can in turn be simplified as @Rohit's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
string dateTime = String.Format("Todays Date: {0}, Current Time: {1}", 
                                 DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"), 
                                 DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
```