# C# Datetime format for portuguese

Tags: c#, datetime-format

My current date time format for Portuguese is `d MMM yyyy` resulted in `1 dez 2017` and I want it to display like this: `1 de dez de 2017`

when I format the date like so `d de MMM de yyyy` I will get this `1 1e dez 1e 2017`

is there a way to bypass the `de` to be transformed to date?

my question is there a way to format the date like this `1 de dez de 2017`?

Comment: exact need is not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to a specified Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371658/convert-datetime-to-a-specified-format)

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724183/how-to-put-unprocessed-escaped-words-inside-string-format

Comment: what does `de` mean? When you pass datetime format it has some special characters which are used for determining what you want to parse (for example `d, M, Y, etc.` ). if you want string `de` to be shown than you need to enclose it into apostrophes `'` so use `'de'`. Try it and reply if it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#escape) the `\d` otherwise it will be recognized as `day of the month`.

```
new DateTime(2017, 12, 1).ToString(@"d \de MMM \de yyyy", new CultureInfo("PT-pt"));
```

[Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pvXumV)

Answer (score 2):

```
new DateTime(2017, 1, 1).ToString("d 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy", new CultureInfo("PT-pt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime`s are formatted with [custom format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can make sure characters aren't formatted as part of the date/time by escaping them.

There are two methods of escaping characters:

- The `\` character can be used to escape a *single* character
- The `'` or `"` characters can be use to escape a string of characters.

The latter is probably easier to use as you can wrap any words in your format string in them and forget about it.

e.g.:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("d 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `d` in `de` has a special meaning, so you have to escape that letter with a backslash.

This concerns all letters that might  conflict with an already predefined date or time format specifier.